# mailsending issues with new mailserver

Tags: asp.net, .net, email, sendmail

i am using for send mail my smtp server is "xxx.xx.x", its working fine. But now i am changing the mail server for emails. i am using new mail smtp server ip address is "xxxxxxx.xxx.xxx", in this case get the error like "The server rejected one or more recipient addresses. The server response was: 554 5.7.1 : Client host "

i am using the bellow code

Dim eMail As MailMessage = New MailMessage

```
    eMail.To = "xxxxxxx"
    eMail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html
    eMail.From = "xxxxxxxx"
    eMail.Subject = "intermedia mail test using 127.0.0.1"
    eMail.Body = sMsg
   SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "xxxxxxx 'AppSettings("MailServer")
    SmtpMail.Send(eMail)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check if the smtp server is configured to accept connections from your client machine, or if the server has some relay restriction enabled ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the mail server is configured to only send mail from certain domains or the client is not in its list of accepted senders.

You need to get in touch with the mail server administrator and ask them to allow the IP address of the machine that the application resides on or send the mail using an address in the correct domain.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1893.txt